# Importing FontAwesome icons by string array in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm having an array of sidebar elements in my React.js project where each element is represented as object which among others has its own FontAwesome icon defined as string, like e.g. `fa-phone`. Now there's a problem with FontAwesome's integration into React.js; each icon has to be separately imported and added to the library, according to their [manual](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react).

```
    import * as React from 'react';

    import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

    interface SidebarElement {
      fa: string,
      href: string,
      title: string
    }

    interface SidebarElements {
      elements: SidebarElement[]
    }

    export default class Sidebar extends React.Component<SidebarElements, {}> {
      render() {

        const elements = this.props.elements.map((element, key) => {

          // tweak icon name so it matches component name...?
          ...

          // the two lines below obviously won't work
          import { element.fa } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
          library.add(element.fa);

          return (
            <li key={key} className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href={element.href}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={element.fa} />
                    <span>{element.title}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
          );
        })

        return (
                <ul className="sidebar navbar-nav">{elements}</ul>
            );
      }
    }
```

But the solution above obviously won't work, since imports have to happen at top-level and won't take the component name from a variable. Are there any alternative ways to import icons without exactly knowing them from the beginning? Or am I forced to import all icons at the same point I'm defining my sidebar elements?

Comment: Yes, you have to import them at the Top-Level. But why don't you just use the normal import via script tag? This sounds very cumbersome.

Comment: FWIW, I tried using FontAwesome via `npm install` and end it with the laziness of listing all the icons I need that I simply added the appropriate `<script>`

Comment: Was considering doing that if nothing else works, but what's the worth of using this integration of FontAwesome then? I thought this would have some advantages over the script tag import, but sadly it seems like it's the other way around...

Answer (score 2):

I went with this same issue on a personal project I'm building. The first problem I found was related to how dynamically rendering the icon from a query?
*Main app container:*

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "../components/header"
import Navigation from "../components/navigation"
import Footer from "../components/footer"
import containerStyles from "./styles.module.less"
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core"
import { fab } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons"

library.add(fab)

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => (
  <div className={containerStyles.home}>
    <div className={containerStyles.menu}>
      <Header />
      <Navigation />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Also, my icons are part of the free-brand version so imported them to the library.

So the first thing I did was to import the library and create a pair of null variables on my child component, one for the prefix and the other one for the icon itself:
[image: child-component-fragmet]

In my project, I'm consuming the data from an API endpoint, the query I built to get the information is the following:
[image]

Theoretically, all was set just for mapping the array and render each item as we normally do:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
   icon={[
      (faprefix = document.node.prefix),
      (faicon = document.node.icon),
    ]}
   size="lg"
 />
```

But the child component was rendering nothing. Why was this? Simply because of both document.node.prefix and document.node.icon are returning strings so when the component mapped the data from the array, it ended trying to render something like this:

```
<svg data-prefix="'fab'" data-icon="'github'" >
```

*Please note the single quotation mark wrapping the string*

My solution to this was to use a replace() method with a regex to remove the wrapping quotations marks:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
   icon={[
      (faprefix = document.node.prefix.replace(/'/g, "")),
      (faicon = document.node.icon.replace(/'/g, "")),
   ]}
   size="lg"
/>
```

*Child footer component*

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import containerStyles from "../pages/styles.module.less"

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"

let faicon = null
let faprefix = null
const Navigation = ({ data }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query FooterTemplate {
        allStrapiLink {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              icon
              url
              prefix
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <>
        <footer>
          <p>Freddy Polanía {new Date().getFullYear()}</p>
          <div className={containerStyles.links}>
            {data.allStrapiLink.edges.map(document => (
              <div key={document.node.id}>
                <a
                  href={document.node.url}
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  target="_blank"
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={[
                      (faprefix = document.node.prefix.replace(/'/g, "")),
                      (faicon = document.node.icon.replace(/'/g, "")),
                    ]}
                    size="lg"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </footer>
      </>
    )}
  />
)

export default Navigation
```

Now my icons are rendering from the endpoint's data. I hope this could help to solve your issue.

Comment: can you please post dummy document object?